# Tuning ASP.Net Framework on IIS

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I have a site that is running on the 4.5 framework which uses `Task.Run` during the pre-init event to fetch and process multiple pieces of data in an effort to reduce the response time.  I'm seeing an avg response time under 500ms that is pretty consistent over the course of the day however every few mins I see response times for individual requests that hit anywhere from 5000ms - 30000ms (which is the configured page request timeout).  The machine.config is set with autoConfig = true in the process model section with no overrides for min/max for either WorkerThreads or IOThreads in either the machines config or web config.

I'm referencing these documents for some details on how autoconfig works and tuning.
[asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/)
[how-to-tune-machine-config-settings-for-improved-performance](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3038429/how-to-tune-machine-config-settings-for-improved-performance.html)

I'm trying to determine if I'm running out of ASP.net WorkerThreads or IoThreads and nothing stands out in the Performance Counters to be able to see this.

Is there a way to see what the running values of the Min/MaxWorkerThreads and Min/MaxIoThreads are? Are there counters on how many Worker and IO threads are being consumed as requests come in?

**Server Details:**

- 4 Core Intel Xeon Platinum 8000 series
- 8 GB Memory
- Windows Server 2016

Comment: Instead of focusing too much on live status (hang dump analysis can easily reveal that), you might also analyze IIS log files to see if during a short period of time tons of requests come and all finish with long processing time. That also confirms you are hitting the classic thread exhaustion issue. You really need to think twice about your current code, as splitting too many tasks sometimes won't lead to better performance as switching contexts is also costy.

Comment: @LexLi that makes sense with the exception of how to you know what the running values are if the autoconfig is enabled?

Comment: Commonly people check dumps via `threadpool` https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/net-debugging-33-finding-asp-net-pages-of-high-cpu-problems/